# concatenate and remove duplicate element from numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, duplicates, concatenation

I compute an array of indices in each iteration of a loop and then I want to remove the duplicate elements and concatenate the computed array to the previous one. 
For example the first iteration gives me this array:

```
array([  1,   6,  56, 120, 162, 170, 176, 179, 197, 204])
```

and the second one:

```
array([ 29,  31,  56, 104, 162, 170, 176, 179, 197, 204])
```

and so on. How could I do it?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setxor1d.html#numpy.setxor1d

Comment: @Ron it removes the duplicated numbers I want to keep them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can concatenate arrays first with `numpy.concatenate` then use `np.unique`

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,6,56,120,162,170,176,179,197,204])
b=np.array([29,31,56,104,162,170,176,179,197,204])
new_array = np.unique(np.concatenate((a,b),0))

print new_array
```

result:

```
[  1   6  29  31  56 104 120 162 170 176 179 197 204]
```

Comment: Looks like you beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) and [`numpy.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
In [81]: arr = np.array([  1,   6,  56, 120, 162, 170, 176, 179, 197, 204])

In [82]: arr = np.unique(np.concatenate((arr, np.array([ 29,  31,  56, 104, 162, 170, 176, 179, 197, 204]))))

In [83]: arr
Out[83]: array([  1,   6,  29,  31,  56, 104, 120, 162, 170, 176, 179, 197, 204])
```

Answer (score 2):

[`numpy.union1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.union1d.html#numpy.union1d) is the one-numpy function you're looking for (in this case).

```
import numpy as np
print( np.union1d([ 1, 6,56,120,162,170,176,179,197,204],\
                  [29,31,56,104,162,170,176,179,197,204]) )
# result
[  1   6  29  31  56 104 120 162 170 176 179 197 204]
```

Comment: Seems a better answer than the currently selected one.